# get the socket name list in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am currently creating the chatting app.

I want to get the all the chat room list.

or else all the connedted socket's name list

```
        //now in the room
        socket.join(roomID);   <---  want to get all connedted socket list
        socket.nickname = name;            
        socket.roomIn = roomID;
        socket.roomName = room;
```

Answer (score 0):

List of all `socket.io` rooms (actually its a list of key,value pairs where the key is the room name and the value is the roomId:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms
```

List of all `socket.io` connections in a room:

```
io.sockets.clients( roomID );
```

Comment: But i want to make clear that.  I want to get all the socket room list. not members in the room